# Which open-source ASP.Net projects are worth looking at for learning efforts?

Tags: c#, asp.net, open-source

I'm trying to create (with your help) a list of open-source asp.net projects that are worth looking at, for reasons like a nice project design, nice solutions for common problems et cetera. The main effort of this list should be, that you feel that you have learned something from viewing a project's source code.

If you do post a project, please provide a link to the project page and tell us, why the project is worthy being metioned here. You can use this template:

**Template**:
Project Name:
URL:
Project Description:
Technologies used:
Why is the project worth looking at?:

**List of recommendable open-source projects**:

- [Nerddinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750556/which-open-source-asp-net-projects-are-worth-looking-at-for-learning-efforts/3751666#3751666)

I'm making this a community wiki, so nobody should complain about this question. Feel free to edit it.

Comment: Not an open-source project, but following the official tutorials (like these ones: http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials) taught me a lot about good project design.

Answer (score 2):

- **Project Name:** [NerdDinner.com - Where Geeks Eat](http://www.nerddinner.com/)
- **URL:** http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/
- **Project Description:** Organizing the world's nerds and helping them eat in packs.
- **Technologies used:**

  - ASP.NET MVC
  - OpenID
  - Virtual Earth
  - Twitter integration
  - iCal events
  - RSS Feeds
- **Why is the project worth looking at?:** The best way to learn a new framework is to build something with it.  This tutorial walks through how to build a small, but complete, application using ASP.NET MVC, and introduces some of the core concepts behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of www.asp.net and aspallaince.com